# Python - Injecting html tags into strings based on regex match

Tags: python, html, regex, string, tags

I wrote a script in Python for custom HTML page that finds a word within a string/line and highlights just that word with use of following tags where instance is the word that is searched for.

```
<b><font color=\"red\">"+instance+"</font></b>
```

With the following result:
[image]

I need to find a word (case insensitive) let's say "port" within a string that can be port, Port, SUPPORT, Support, support etc, which is easy enough.

```
pattern = re.compile(word, re.IGNORECASE)
find_all_instances = pattern.findall(string_to_search)
```

However my strings often contain 2 or more instances in single line, and I need to append 
`<b><font color=\"red\">"+instance+"</font></b>` to each of those instances, without changing cases.

Problem with my approach, is that I am attempting to itterate over each of instances found with findall (exact match), 
while multiple same matches can also be found within the string.

```
for instance in find_all_instances:
    second_pattern = re.compile(instance)
    string_to_search = second_pattern.sub("<b><font color=\"red\">"+instance+"</font></b>", string_to_search)
```

This results in following:

```
<b><font color="red"><b><font color="red"><b><font color="red">Http</font></b></font></b></font></b></font>
```

when I need

```
<b><font color="red">Http</font></b>
```

I was thinking, I would be able to avoid this if I was able to find out exact part of the string that the pattern.sub substitutes at the moment of doing it, 
however I was not able to find any examples of that kind of usage, which leads me to believe that I am doing something very wrong.

If anyone have a way I could use to insert `<b><font color="red">instance</font></b>` without replacing `instance` for all matches(case insensitive), then I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misinterpretting your question, but wouldn't re.sub be the best option?

Example: https://repl.it/DExs

Answer (score 0):

Okay so two ways I did quickly! The second loop is definitely the way to go. It uses re.sub (as someone else commented too). It replaces with the lowercase search term bear in mind.

```
import re

FILE = open("testing.txt","r")
word="port"

#THIS LOOP IS CASE SENSITIVE
for line in FILE:
    newline=line.replace(word,"<b><font color=\"red\">"+word+"</font></b>")
    print newline

#THIS LOOP IS INCASESENSITIVE
for line in FILE:
    pattern=re.compile(word,re.IGNORECASE)
    newline = pattern.sub("<b><font color=\"red\">"+word+"</font></b>",line)
    print newline
```